# Scroll from a link in static sidebar to include element in footer

Tags: javascript, jekyll

I have set up a [Jekyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jekyll_%28software%29) blog, and the theme has a static left navigation bar. I want to link from “About” in this nav bar, to take the reader to the last item in the footer of any active page, specifically to an accordion of related "About" snippets. This accordion is an {% include…} element.

I can't get standard HTML anchor code to work, and the JavaScript tips I have seen here don’t seem to accommodate the idea that the link is in a static sidebar and the destination is an include in a footer.

I have looked at linked headers (I can put a header above the accordion), but this linked header approach seems to apply to headers within a post or page, not a sitewide element like a footer. I am out my depth trying to modify a script. How can I trick the browser?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a minute to have a look at the [tour about how to post](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please consider that we should have a look at some code to be able to help you. :)

Comment: Why trick the browser ? You can also make a nice about page, with some useful informations and a nice picture on it. The plus, is that it will be found by (the) search engine. KISS

Comment: Thanks for the advice on the About page, David. I could do that, and I may well have to, but after reading around this site and others, I have exhausted my limited thinking options, and am trying to see if there is a way to achieve this "move", to scroll from a sidebar to a footer, or is it a completely flawed idea? cheers

Comment: I had this answer from a developer at work. "From what you have written it does not seem to require JS at all. If you create a div with an attribute id="aboutSection", you can link any element with an <a> tag with the attribute href="#aboutSection" and the page will jump to where that div is on the page once clicked. You can get various jQuery plugins so that the jump is a slow easing scroll too." I followed this advice and the jump works, now to make a more refined jump. Thanks.